# rapidly change data type of table in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, types, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table with >100 columns imported from excel to access 2007, and I want to change all the datatype of the fields into memo, being fed up of manually clicking the datatype pull down list one by one, can I do it by VBA or SQL statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf1 As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ssi_10q12_v5_table")
Set tdf1 = db.CreateTableDef("ssi_10q12_v5_table_1")


    Debug.Print tdf.Name,
    Debug.Print tdf.Fields.Count
    For x = 0 To tdf.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print tdf.Fields(x).Name,
        Set fld = tdf1.CreateField(tdf.Fields(x).Name, dbMemo)
        tdf1.Fields.Append fld

    Next x

db.TableDefs.Append tdf1
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

See if this can help anyone here, thanks again.

Comment: This creates a new field, not changing the data type of an existing field. Is it intended as an answer to the actual question?

Comment: i planned to create a new table, and replace this with the original one

Comment: Well, that information would have been a helpful part of your question!